# Add-in Installed from Network Reverts to Local Path? (Excel 2016)

Tags: excel, vba, add-in

I am attempting to deploy a custom MS Excel add-in across our network environment following this article: https://www.excelguru.ca/content.php?152-Deploying-Add-ins-in-a-Network-Environment.

One users computer is causing trouble for me.  I install as directed, specifically when asked, I say "NO" to copying the file to the local user's folder.  Initially the add-in appears to have installed and work properly.  However, upon restarting Excel, I find that in fact, Excel gives the error message stating the add-in is missing and has a file path to the local users folder.  I have tried multiple times to the same outcome.

On other users PC's (win7 and win10 boxes) the file installs fine from the network and remains after a restart of Excel.  So far, the issue appears to be isolated to one user's PC.  He is on windows 10 and excel 2016.

Has anyone encountered this?  To me seems like a bug maybe?

Comment: The article you refer to indicates you should indicate the directory in your network like `F:\Addins`. I cannot remember 100%, but I think we had similar issues in my company and were able to solve that by indicating the directory like `\\servername.domain.name\etc.`

Comment: @EarlyBird2 that path is only for deploying updates to the add-in from my development machine.  I am referring to issues with one of the users machines not retaining the reference to the network add-in, and instead creating some internal reference to a local file, even though I have said not to copy the file over.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've seen that happen if the user initially selects to copy it locally, then removes it, and then tries to add the network copy. The only fix is to edit the registry to remove the local reference, and then add the network copy again.

It's important for the end users to not copy the file locally the first time, or you end up in this mess.

Search their registry for the filename of the add-in and delete it.